# Where does Apache Derby store its files when used with Apache Qpid?

Tags: derby, amqp, qpid

I'm using [Derby DB](http://db.apache.org/derby/) as storage for my [Qpid broker](http://qpid.apache.org/). Trying to figure out where Derby store the data files when running as embedded db.

Anyone has a clue where the files are located or how to set the directory to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the following variables:

`QPID_HOME` - specifies where your install of Qpid exists, used for broker lookups of files etc

`QPID_WORK` - defines location of all working files created by the broker including log and **db** (i.e. BDB if used). Note that the `QPID_WORK` variable defaults to the current user's home directory if not set.

Answer (score 4):

This is determined by the [derby.system.home](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.1.2/ref/rrefproper32066.html#rrefproper32066) property.

> Specifies the Derby system directory, which is the directory that
>   contains subdirectories holding databases that you create and the text
>   file derby.properties.

Each database has a corresponding directory named after the database. The file structure under this directory is documented [here](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.0/manuals/develop/develop13.html).

Comment: Yes, it seems to be right if you use derby as a standalone. In this case setting the QPID_WORK environment variable solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen in the Derby documentation that the Derby database consists of datafiles and one service.properties file.
If you are using Netbeans and Java DB alias Derby on Windows 7, all the databases are stored in
C:\users\your_user_name\.netbeans-derby\your_database\seg0.